# How to make all links in Div open in the same window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, blogger

I use Blogger Dynamic Slider by shuvojitdas (http://bloggerslider.shuvojitdas.com/2016/02/blogger-dynamic-slider-by-label-or-recent-posts.html)
The code is as it follows:

```
<!-- BloggerDynamicSlider Basic CSS -->
<style type="text/css">
/**
 *  jQuery BloggerDynamicSlider v1.0.0
 *  Copyright 2016 http://shuvojitdas.com
 *  Contributing Author: Shuvojit Das
 *  Plugin URL: https://github.com/shuvojit33/blogger-dynamic-slider
 *
 */

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400);
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.0/flexslider.min.css");

/* Preloader */

.flexslider.loading:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-WWve06d4dB4/Vq28tN4LMUI/AAAAAAAAFcM/k8IQajpDnS4/h120/loader.gif) no-repeat center center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    z-index: 9999;
}

.flexslider.loading ul.flex-direction-nav,
.flexslider.loading ol,
.loading .flex-caption {
    display: none;
}

.flexslider {
    border: 1px solid #cacaca;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0 auto 60px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.flexslider a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


/* Caption/Post Title */

.flex-caption {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #1C1C1C;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flex-caption span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 60px;
}

.flex-caption.overlayDark,
.flex-caption.overlayLight {
    margin-bottom: -60px;
    bottom: 60px;
    position: relative;
}

.flex-caption.overlayDark {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: #fff;
}

.flex-caption.overlayLight {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 239, 0.9);
    color: #000;
}

ul.slides li a {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}


/* blogger css conflicts fix */

.flexslider ul {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    line-height: initial !important;
}

.flexslider ul.flex-direction-nav li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: initial;
}

.flexslider ul li {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.flexslider img {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

ul.flex-direction-nav {
    position: static;
}

ul.flex-direction-nav li {
    position: static;
}

.error {
    font-family: monospace, sans-serif;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .flex-caption {
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
}
</style>
<!-- Include Dependency Script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.0/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shuvojitdas.com/script/jquery.bdslider.min.js"></script>
```

And:

```
<div id="slider1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slider1").BloggerDynamicSlider({
        imageWidth: 636, // Image width in px value
        imageHeight: 398, // Image height in px value
        maxItem: 6, // Max number of Slider Image to show
        animation: "slide", // Select your animation type, "fade" or "slide"
        showPostTitle: true, // Show post title as Caption ? (true/false)
        postTitleStyle: "overlayLight", // Caption style: "default, "overlayDark" or "overlayLight"
    });
});
</script>
```

However, I'd like all the links to open in the same window and they are opening in a new one. I tried the following code:

```
jQuery('#slider1>a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).attr('target', '_top');
});
```

and it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the slider have a config for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by updating your jQuery selector as below.

```
jQuery('#slider1 a').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).attr('target', '_top');
});
```

Comment: That's nice. Select the answer as the solution, so that It can be helpful for others as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove target="_blank" attribute from "a" tag in the slider. That should solve the problem.

Comment: Yep editing that markup and removing that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
jQuery('#slider1>a').attr('target', '_top');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

jQuery('#slider1>a').click(function(){

jQuery(this).attr('target', '_self');

})